# JavaScript function always return false even if a value is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function returns `true` or `false` but what I see is this function always returns `false`.

```
  const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
    const isLastImage =
      filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
    console.log(`isLastImage:`, isLastImage); // true
    return isLastImage ? true : false;
  };

  console.log('isLastImageAttachment()', isLastImageAttachment()); // false
```

`isLastImage` returns `true` or `false` but `isLastImageAttachment` always return `false` even if `isLastImage` is `true`.

What is wrong with it?

#### Attempts

I return `isLastImage` itself.

```
  const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
    const isLastImage =
      filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
    console.log(`isLastImage:`, isLastImage); // true
    return isLastImage;
  };
```

But `isLastImageAttachment` returns `false`.

Of course just return `true`, I got return `true`

```
  const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
    return true;
  };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Impossible to say as it stands. This code wouldn't run anyway because you're not passing in an index, so `attachments[undefined]` would throw an error. Also, note that `isTrue ? true : false` is redundant. You can just `return isLastImage`.

Comment: Note that `return isLastImage ? true : false;` is exactly the same as `return isLastImage;` Also, we have no idea what `filteredImages` is, or `attachments`.

Comment: @AleksandrH: `attchments[undefined]` won't throw but `undefined.uuid` would.

Comment: Re last edit: You've managed to double the length of your question without including a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: `console.log('isLastImageAttachment()', isLastImageAttachment()); // false` You don't pass `index` to the function...

Comment: @AleksandrH Thank you for your answer! I added my attempts while you were posting the comment but `return isLastImage; ` also return `false`

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes... that's so true I didn't pass `idx` and probably why I'm getting only `false`. Thank you and let me try with passding `idx`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 100% sure the is "islastimage" return true
if not check your index param

```
 const isLastImage = filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
```

Then your code is correct just change what I mentioned  down blow

```
  const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
    const isLastImage =
      filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
    console.log(`isLastImage:`, isLastImage); // true

    // instade of this 
    // return isLastImage ? true : false;
    // just do this (I just simplified your return code line)

    return isLastImage
  };

  console.log('isLastImageAttachment ==>', isLastImageAttachment());
```

You can simplified your function more:

```
const isLastImageAttachment = index => filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you in your function just return isLastImmage itself?
Like this:

```
const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
const isLastImage =
  filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
console.log(`isLastImage:`, isLastImage); // true
return isLastImage;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to this:

```
const isLastImageAttachment = index => filteredImages.uuid === atachments[index].uuid
```

To fix your problem let's try a little debug.
First of all try to put console.log in your code to make sure that filteredImages.uuid and atachments[index].uuid exist. Then try to check their types with help of typeof.

Also just a guess but, filteredImages sounds like an array

Answer (score 0):

```
const isLastImageAttachment = index => {
    const isLastImage =
      filteredImages.uuid === attachments[index].uuid;
    console.log(`isLastImage:`, isLastImage); // true
    return isLastImage ? true : false;
  };

  console.log('isLastImageAttachment()', isLastImageAttachment());
```

As it stands the function works correctly. It return false because it should return false. attachments[index].uuid is false because when you execute the function you are not passing any parameter into it. So. Index is undefined. attachments[index].uuid is undefined. so it will return false. Pass the index.

Also. Try to add at least a mockup of the data array so in a future people can help you better.